# How to add dynamic padding-top and bottom according to my menu div

Tags: jquery, html, css

when i click on hamburger, a menu div is shown, height of menu div is add  dynamically. But the padding-top and bottom between the menu is fixed. I want to add dynamic padding-top and bottom according to my menu div. 
[Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vL4b.png)

Here's my jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).ready(function(){
    var subtractvalue=7;
    var divide=42;
    var innerpadding= $(".menu_height_mobile").height();
    var final=(innerpadding / divide);
    var ptb= Math.round(final - subtractvalue );
    alert(ptb);
    //alert(ptb)
     $(".add_dynamic_pd").css({'padding-top': +ptb+"px", "padding-bottom": +ptb+"px"
    })

 })
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide your html code (only the part necessary to depict your problem) as well.

Comment: What is the purpose of the padding?

Comment: the purpose of padding that my  content stretch on full screen. because my screen height change dynamically, so if i fix the padding that's not looking responsive. @EranGoldin

Comment: You don’t need to do all that to just center your content. Use a flexbox